# How to call VueJs method in vue-worker?

Tags: vue.js, web-worker

I have a method like below

```
methods: {
    workerJob(){
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            count ++;
        }
        return count;
   }
}
```

how can i call this method using vue-worker - [Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-worker)

I tried this simple way, but its giving error

```
this.$worker.run(this.workerJob());

Uncaught ReferenceError: _this is not defined
```

How to pass external methods to **worker.postMessage()** like below

```
worker.postMessage('func1')
  .then(console.log) // logs 'Worker 1: Working on func1'
  .catch(console.error) // logs any possible error
```

Comment: Can you try to bind the 'this' context to a variable first ? const self = this; this.$worker.run(self.workerJob());

Comment: Since "You can pass this.$data or any variable within data or computed", you could also try to bind workerJob to a data property and pass it as an argument then.

Comment: i tried `self` not working and workerJob() is larger method so i need to call that function insight worker. not out sight to assign another data variable.